# Android IMEI binding with music file

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to develop an application that binds the IMEI with the music file and should not play that music file if IMEI is not registered.

The core idea is to protect the licensed file from transferring to other devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using popular file formats like MP3, WAV etc, then any such protection you implement will only work in your app. The user will still be able to transfer the music file and play it using another music player.

However, you could develop a custom format that stores the IMEI as a part of the file (though you should store a hash of it, instead of the raw number, both for security and privacy reasons). This format will have to be structured in a way that no media player but yours can read the data from it. Naturally, you'll have to develop a parser for this format as well, as Android's built in media classes won't be able to play this.

Also, keep in mind that there are many Android devices that don't have an IMEI, so you might want to go with Bluetooth/WiFi MAC addresses. Also, your users may switch devices, and all of a sudden their music won't play anymore.

Comment: Can i use drm concepts in here.

Comment: @sha DRM concepts is a very broad term.